# How to detect this unprintable character using regex or other ways in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, character-encoding

I came upon a strange character (using Nokogiri).

```
irb(main):081:0> sss.dump
=> "\"\\u{a0}\""
irb(main):082:0> puts sss 

=> nil 
irb(main):083:0> sss 
=> " " 
irb(main):084:0> sss =~ /\s/
=> nil 
irb(main):085:0> sss =~ /[[:print:]]/
=> 0
irb(main):087:0> sss == ' ' 
=> false
irb(main):088:0> sss.length
=> 1
```

Any idea what is this strange character?

When it's displayed in a webpage, it's a white space, but it doesn't match a whitespace \s
using regular expression.  Ruby even thinks it's a printable character!

How do I detect characters like this and exclude them or flag them as whitespace (if possible)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's the non-breaking space. In HTML, it's used pretty frequently and often written as &nbsp;. One way to find out the identity of a character like `"\u{a0}"` is to search the web for `U+00A0` (using four or more hexadecimal digits) because that's how the Unicode specification notates Unicode code points.

The non-breaking space and other things like it are included in the regex `/[[:space:]]/`.